# Proper way to replace string prefix in C

Tags: c, copy, c-strings

My goal is to replace the first `n` (3) characters in a string without getting any compiler warnings or triggering undefined behavior:

```
const char *replacment = "abc";
char buffer[128] = "xxx-remainder";
```

I am using gcc (GCC) 9.2.0 with just the standard library:

1. Using `sprintf` appears to be inserting the NUL character in `replacement` even through I think I'm telling it not to:

   ```
   sprintf(buffer, "%.3s", replacement);
   printf("%s\n", buffer);   /// prints "abc", not "abc-remainder"
   ```
2. Using `strncpy` raises a warning:

   ```
   strncpy(buffer, replacement, 3);
   ```

   This triggers the following warning:

   ```
   test.c: In function 'main':
   main.c:8:5: warning: 'strncpy' output truncated before terminating nul copying 3 bytes from a string of the same length [-Wstringop-truncation]
    8 |         strncpy(buffer, replacement, 3);
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   ```

   The output appears fine in this case.
3. Of course, I can copy the characters manually using a `for` loop, but I'm trying to avoid that.

How do I fix either of the approaches shown here, or what alternative function call would allow me to replace the first 3 characters without inserting a NUL into the string or getting warnings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
memcpy(buffer, replacement, strlen(replacement));
```

is what you are looking for.

Another (very obfuscated) way:

```
char c = buffer[strlen(replacement)];
buffer[snprintf(buffer, sizeof buffer, "%s", replacement)] = c;
```

Comment: I think the +1 is extra. I'm specifically trying not to insert the trailing `'\0'`

Comment: oops, let me check that

Comment: Do you know enough about `sprintf` formats to fix my original approach?

Comment: Sorry, @MadPhysicist, the closest I can get with `sprintf` and friends is `buffer[snprintf(buffer, sizeof buffer, "%s", replacement)] = c;`, you can not skip the trailing NUL with them.

Comment: Wow. I've been staring at it for a while now. Finally realized that my format spec is fine. That's not where the NUL is coming from :)

Answer (score 1):

Just use memcpy.

```
memcpy( buffer, replacement, 3 );
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{
    const char *replacment = "abc";
    char buffer[128] = "xxx-remainder";
    
    printf( "%s\n", ( char * )memcpy( buffer, replacment, strlen( replacment ) ) );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
abc-remainder
```

Answer (score 1):

Making the number of characters a variable makes the `strncpy` approach work without a warning:

```
const char *replacment = "abc";
char buffer[128] = "xxx-remainder";

const int n = 3;
strncpy(buffer, replacement, n);
```

The `const` qualifier is optional.

Apparently the warning was a bug in version 9.0: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=87028 and was subsequently fixed. Presumably somewhere between 9.2 and 10.2.

Comment: Strange, I'm using gcc whith warnings on including Wstringop-truncation: `gcc -std=c11 -Wpedantic -Wall -Wextra  -Wstringop-truncation ` and `strncpy(buffer, replacement, 3);` is not giving any warning. I'm on Ubuntu 20.04 if it matters. gcc 10.2.0

Comment: @DavidRanieri. Weird. It's probably heavily version dependent then. That seems like such an odd thing to check for anyway.

Comment: @DavidRanieri. Thanks for pointing it out. I did some digging and apparently it's a bug that was fixed between versions 9 and 10. I added a link to my answer.

Comment: Yes, if at least it was `enum { n = 3; }` (a real constant) it wil make more sense, but `int n = 3` and plain 3 are of the same type. you can check with your gcc version in godbolt and see if it raises any warning: https://godbolt.org/z/YMP6f8

Comment: Ohhh, I see, is a bug in your gcc version,